# How to find a summation of a sequence?

Tags: notation, summation

I am working in analyzing an algorithm in recurrence, but I end up in the following sequence:

$$\frac5{2^6}n^2+\frac5{2^4}n^2+\frac5{2^2}n^2+n^2$$

I tried to make an equivalent summation but I failed. Is there a technique on making summations?

Comment: It’s not clear just what sum you’re taking. Are you summing the displayed expression over some range of values of $n$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I mean how can I represent this sequence in the sigma (Σ) notation.

Comment: Just these four terms? I wouldn’t bother, though you could combine the first three and make it $$n^2+5n^2\sum_{k=1}^3\frac1{2^{2k}}\;.$$

Comment: MIH, the word "sequence" doesn't mean what you think it means. Sequences have commas; summations have plus signs.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^N (\frac {5 n^2} {2^{2k}} +\frac {n^2} N)
$$

Without knowing more about the algorithm you are analyzing, it is kind of difficult to provide  the correct summation.

The above sum will give the expression in your question with N=3.